# How can I make a bouncing label in WPF xaml? (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I'm stuck with my school assignment and it should be ready soon, so I hope someone could help me. I've been searching for a solution for hours. I'm sure this is a very simple thing, but I just can't figure it out.

So I'm trying to make a label move in a specific area so that it bounces from "borders" (an area defined with From/To) and takes a new direction. So far I have only managed to make it move up and down, left and right or from corner to corner, but not in every direction. I have no idea how I'm supposed to implement this. This is my xaml code:

```
    <Canvas Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,0,0,0" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227">
        <Label Content="GKO" Height="40" Name="labelGKO" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="6" Width="61" FontSize="8">
            <Label.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName="labelGKO" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                From="0"  To="180" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                From="0" To="50" Duration="0:0:1"
                                AutoReverse="True" />
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.FontSize)"
                                To="24" Duration="0:0:1"
                                AutoReverse="True" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Label.Triggers>
        </Label>
    </Canvas>
```

This makes the label move from up left corner to the bottom right and then up. Then it starts from the beginning. It is clear I don't understand the logic behind it. Should I do multiple Storyboards or DoubleAnimations? Or can I somehow change the course of the label during one animation? How can I tell the label where exactly to go after it has reached a border?

Comment: You aren't going to get bouncing behaviour from Storyboards. You need to write some code that runs logic on a regular schedule.

Comment: Try setting the [`StoryBoard.AutoReverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.autoreverse(v=vs.110).aspx) to true.